# Add a server to SharePoint Admin user?

Tags: permissions, active-directory, sql-server

I need to add one of our production servers (that hosts SQL Server 2008) let's say XXX to SharePoint Admin in SharePoint 2010. How can I do that?

I agree that a server is not a user or a group. Let me share a background. I'm in a process of running a SSIS package from SQL Job. The package extracts data from a SharePoint list to sql table using http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/17652
When I run it as myself( I have access to SharePoint server site), it runs fine. But when I try to run as a system user, it fails.

SO i m thinking of a way to add the server XXX  that hosts SQL Server to the SharePoint farm so that SharePoint when sees that ok here's SQL Job from XXX as a System user is trying to access my list items, so lets grant it access!

Comment: What do you mean, "add it to SharePoint admin"?

Comment: I meant to add XXX like adding a group/user in SharePoint farm and giving it the full control rights.

Comment: A server is not a user or group. Again, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @John Saunders- I edited the Question. Hope it helps. TIA.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just run the SQL job as a specific user.

Comment: Trying to achieve Automation... run it every night at specified time. Thanks.

Comment: But why not run it every night at a specified time, as a specified user?

Comment: Yes running it every night at a specified time, as a specified user is possible. Just wondering if there's a way to run it as a system. Been running all the jobs as a System user, that's why.

Comment: The "system user" is not a system. It's a user named "SYSTEM".

Comment: this might be a lame question but SYSTEM user in XXX, i.e., XXX/SYSTEM is not an Active directory user right?

Comment: That is correct. Those built-in accounts are specific to particular machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply run the nightly job under the identity of a specific user who is granted specific rights to the SharePoint site. That way, you get your automation, but also get control of what the specific user is permitted to access.

I recommend creating a new user instead of reusing an existing user. This will create a sort of "separation of concerns".

Comment: I agree John. Thanks for your patience in providing prompt responses. :) But I don't think you can add a prod server XXX just like that in SharePoint farm right? And again, creating a new user instead of reusing an existing user will again go through the process of putting that user in active directory to be able to add him/her to SharePoint farm right?

Comment: That is correct. Create a specific user like, "DOMAIN\auto-user1" and add that user to the farm with only the access privileges required.